# how to pass return code to an at_exit function

Tags: c, linux, exit, glibc, exit-code

is there a "built-in" way to know the exit code passed to `exit` inside an exit handler installed with `atexit`?

For example, if a call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`, my handler will perform different operations than in case of `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`.

I could solve that with a global variable, but that would negate the comfort of calling `exit` no matter where in my program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `atexit` no. But you could use the [`on_exit`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Cleanups-on-Exit) function :

> Function: int on_exit (void (*function)(int status, void *arg), void *arg)
>
> This function is a somewhat more powerful variant of atexit. It accepts two
>   arguments, a function function and an arbitrary pointer
>   arg. At normal program termination, the function is called with two
>   arguments: the status value passed to exit, and the arg.
>
> This function is included in the GNU C Library only for compatibility
>   for SunOS, and may not be supported by other implementations.

Well, you must use gnu libc ...

Comment: Yeah, I always forget to write that I use glibc. Thanks.